# Print or Convert HTML file to PDF using VBA/Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, pdf

all.

I have some thousands of html files that i have to attach to email messages and send. Problem is that the files have images embeded in `img` tags, so when the user receives and opens the file attached, it is displayed wrong.

The first idea I had to solve this problem was to open each file in a browser and then print to PDF.

I've come with two approaches, and none of it works as expected:

1 - Opening html file in internet explorer and then using the PDFcreator object to print, messes with some barcode coded in the html, turning the pdf created useless.

2 -Opening html file in internet explorer and then using "Microsoft Print to PDF" virtual printer saves the file as expected - all images, right barcodes - but it prompts for a file name and save path for each file before saving.

Second approach seems to return a better result. Actually it just is not practical.

So, is there any way to avoid the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer prompt, setting path and file name programmatically in excel vba?

And how do i make `ExecWB` wait before starting a new loop?

PDFcreator approach:

```
Sub PrintViaPDFCREATOR()

    'Creates PDF Creator object, killing any if already opened:    
    Dim pdfjob As PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
    Do
        DoEvents
        bRestart = False
        Set pdfjob = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
        If pdfjob.cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup") = False Then
            Shell "taskkill /f /im PDFCreator.exe", vbHide
            Set pdfjob = Nothing
            bRestart = True
        End If
    Loop Until bRestart = False

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objfolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objfiles As Scripting.Files
    Dim F As Scripting.File

    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyFolder\"
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set objfolder = FSO.GetFolder(FilePath)
    Set objfiles = objfolder.Files
    For Each F In objfiles

        IE.Navigate2 F.Path
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'PDF creator Settings
        With pdfjob
            .cOption("UseAutoSave") = 1
            .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
            .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = FilePath
            .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = Replace(F.Name, ".htm", ".pdf")
            .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0    ' 0 = PDF
            .cClearCache
        End With

        'Prints without prompt :)
        IE.ExecWB 6, 2, "", ""

        'Hold on til Job is finished
        Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 1
            DoEvents
        Loop

        pdfjob.cPrinterStop = False

        'Check if there is any file in the queue
        Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 0
            DoEvents
        Loop

    Next

    pdfjob.cClose
    Set pdfjob = Nothing

End Sub
```

Issue with this code: There is some barcodes in the html file composed by many `div`s of 1 to 2px borders. By this method, the pdf has unrecognizable barcodes. It seems like it merges some of the "bars" during conversion, making it unreadeable to optic scanner.

Microsoft Print to PDF approach:

```
Sub PrintViaMicrosoftToPDF()
    'Save the current active printer for later reset:
    Dim OldPrinter
    OldPrinter = Trim(Split(Application.ActivePrinter, "in")(0))

    'Define the new active printer
    CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter "Microsoft Print to PDF"

    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objfolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objfiles As Scripting.Files
    Dim F As Scripting.File

    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyFolder\"
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set objfolder = FSO.GetFolder(FilePath)
    Set objfiles = objfolder.Files

    For Each F In objfiles

        IE.Navigate2 F.Path
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Prints but prompts :(
        IE.ExecWB 6, 2, "", ""

    Next

    'Reset Printer
    CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter OldPrinter
End Sub
```

Issue with this code: It prints the right document in pdf, but the user has to choose save path and file name.

If there is other way of sending the html files attached to eamil message with the embeded images without conversion, or with other approches regarding to file conversion, i'm gradly accepting too.

But i'm limited to Excel/Vba.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2c99c72-d8ab-4912-8479-a1482b774cde/make-a-pdf-of-a-web-page-with-vba-code-in-excel?forum=excel

Comment: Thanks, Miqi180. But the solution in the link relies on the use of PDFcreator for print service. The code to print tvia PDFcreator is not a problem, the one i posted works. The issue is that PDFcreator application does not convert the html files appropriately, making html formated barcodes unusable, Be it programmatically or manually.

Comment: @Musicodelic Ever have any luck with this? I'm in a similar situation and everything I try has failed. I thought a solution to your issue would potentially help my issue too.

I'm looping through URLs and trying to print the html as a PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF, but I can't even get the print dialog box to appear, it just skips to the next URL.

Comment: @TBoulz Since my goal was to attach to an email a file with embeded image in it, i gave up this PDF approach and instead, found a way to embed it directly to the html file.